# Failed to find network address

Tags: streaming, rtsp, live555, sdp, rtsp-client

i installed openRTSP on UBUNTU and try to call url rtsp://simplelive.nexg.tv:554/starplus_mpeg.sdp using the command

```
openRTSP rtsp://simplelive.nexg.tv:554/starplus_mpeg.sdp
```

i am getting the error

```
Failed to get a SDP description for the URL "rtsp://simplelive.nexg.tv:554/starjalsha_mpeg.sdp": Failed to find network address for "simplelive.nexg.tv"
```

i want to get description of the screen can anyone please suggest why i am getting this error and how to resolve it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message sounds like that openRTSP can't find the host simplelive.nexg.tv.
Try within a terminal window: ping simplelive.nexg.tv

If the ping can't resolve the name or your host is not reachable than you have a network problem that is unrelated to openRTSP.

I'd search for UBUNTU basic network troubleshooting -

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=25557